# In echarts, is there a way to make format 'time' on xAxis to a specified timezone without formatter?

Tags: echarts

It would be nice to have a global option to specify how times should be displayed; is this something that is available? Or is the only option to specify a formatter for each chart?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the Echarts has no global option for formatter. How are you will use one formatter for tooltip, labels, series, axis and other different data types?

1. You can define one function and use it wherever.
2. You can extend chart instance and bind our formatter as method, but is a bad practice.
3. Echarts (singleton) has template helpers for formation and maybe you can use it https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/4ffd864e9134fb61d549c2d0567c6d18bf23e504/src/util/format.js

Comment: I'm not looking for a single formatter globally; I want to specify which timezone dates should be displayed. It already has the concept of a 'time' type, and makes the decision to display it in UTC. I want the option to specify a different default, without having to replace the formatter at all.

Thanks for the suggestions though I will give them a look over :)